What is a "Red Directive"?
In universe, what's involved with a "Red Directive"? I get the impression that like the Omega Directive, certain rules and regs get rescinded.
I don't remember there being any mention of Red Directives before season 5 of Discovery, though they might have been mentioned somewhere before that I've not seen or read (either canon in-universe or something official from the studios or producers).

They invented it for the show, along with a bunch of other canon-busting nonsense; https://screenrant.com/star-trek-discovery-red-directive-new-protocol-explanation/

I wonder if Lower Decks should do a bit about all these protocols Starfleet personnel are apparently supposed to know by heart, and getting confused between a Beige Alert and a Taupe Directive...

Unsurprisingly there's been no mention of a "red directive" in any of the licenced Star Trek novels, nor any episode before this one. It appears to be a 'Starfleet in the future' thing where anything goes as long as the mission succeeds.

maybe it means that if they get caught red-handed,  then starfleet will deny any responsibility

It's more important than an orange directive, but less important than a mauve one. Most importantly, it doesn't mean changing the lightbulb.

They probably send the total Smegheads out to do the orange directives :P
